# Page numbers in CSS

Tags: html, css, printing, footer, page-numbering

I need page numbers on a printed HTML page.  I saw a few examples on the Web of how to do this with CSS that appear not to work at all.  Is there any way to insert a footer with page numbers, at all on any web browser?  Is this something that only worked in older browser versions?

Comment: Adding page number in the footer of a page will be the feature of the print dialog rather than page's content